# Foursquare API + Neighborhoods

Tags: api, foursquare

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the Foursquare API to determine the neighborhood of a particular address? For example, if a user entered an address, could I use the Foursquare API to pre-populate a neighborhood field?

Answer (score 0):

The Foursquare API doesn't outright provide any geocoding services like you're asking for. However, we do help maintain a geocoding library called [twofishes](http://twofishes.net/) that you can possibly explore using.

Answer (score 0):

this query https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_secret=xxxx&client_id=cccc&limit=50&venuePhotos=1&v=20140327&near=Los%20Angeles,CA&radius=40000&categoryId=4f2a25ac4b909258e854f55f

gives the neighborhood information for a city.